# is there a way to add a <label></label> to every column header using Material Table React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

Hi I am trying to add a `<label></label>` to every cell of table. I am using Material table here: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding

I tried like this:

```js
<Table
  onChangePage={handleChangePage}
  page={props.currentPage}
  totalCount={props.totalCount}
  options={{
    paging:true,
    pageSizeOptions:[10, 15, 25, 50],
    pageSize: props.rowsPerPage,
    padding: "dense",
    search: false,
    toolbar:false,
    headerStyle: TableHeaderRow, <--- cssproperties
    rowStyle:TableRow <--- cssproperties
  }}
  columns={columns} <--- variable columns:TableColumn[]
  data={dataAct} <---- data generated from API
/>
```

Actually, I defined the `headerStyle` in options, but what I really want is adding a

```
<label>
  headerValueHere}
</label>
```

for every header.

I added label tag to cells like using render in defining columns:

```js
const getDocumentTypeForRow = rowData => {
  return (
    <Tooltip title={rowData}>
      <label style={OpenVulnerabilityDuePatchingCardDetailsElementLabel}>
        {rowData}
      </label>
    </Tooltip>
  )
};

const columns: TableColumn<>[] = [
  {
    title: 'Due Date',
    field: 'remediation_due_date',
    render: data => getDocumentTypeForRow(data.remediation_due_date)
  },
]
```

**But how to do this for headers???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pass JSX or HTML to title

```
const columns: TableColumn<>[] = [
  {
    title: <label>Due Date</label>,
    field: 'remediation_due_date',
    render: data => getDocumentTypeForRow(data.remediation_due_date)
  },
]
```

You may do live editing here and see the results

https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/styling

```
columns={[
        {
          title: <h1>Heading 1</h1>, field: 'name',
          cellStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#039be5',
            color: '#FFF'
          },
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#039be5',
          }
        },
        { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
        { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
        {
          title: 'Birth Place',
          field: 'birthCity',
          lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
        },
      ]}
```